# Encountered an error executing step in job

Tags: spring-batch

Can someone help me resolve this? 
I'm getting an error:

```
Encountered an error executing step in job: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must be assigned for the sake of defining the execution context keys prefix
```

Comment: Looks like you have an item reader or writer which has not been assigned a name, hence Spring Batch is unable to serialize/deserialize the execution context. 
Please share your config to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks for the response. Actually I fixed it by putting a @StepScope on my reader.

Comment: Great! Glad you fixed your issue. Next time, try to provide as much details as possible to be able to help you in an efficient way (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6):

I don't use XML anymore so this is what worked for me:

I am using `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` as a parent abstract class for my reader.

I just called the method `setName()` in the overridden function `doOpen()`.

```
@Override
protected void doOpen() throws Exception {
   source = service.findMyData();
   setName(MyReader.class.getName());
}
```

Hope it helps somebody !

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by using @StepScope annotation in my reader.

Thanks